# Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate

Tags: netsuite, transfer, zoho

I am transferring data from the Zoho sales order to the Net Suite order. But I am getting this error. I have checked the items in the NetSuite items records items was there. Please help me with this.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this various times. Sometimes the fix is simple and sometimes it seems quite temporary and the issue goes away.

1. If you are creating your sales order in dynamic mode make sure you set things up in the order in which you'd do it in the UI. e.g. intialize from customer , set the shipping address, set a shipping method, add items.
2. Check whether the customer has a default shipping method. If it does then clear it (open customer, clear default ship method, save customer) before creating your sales order
3. Check your Netsuite shipping configuration. You may have a UPS realtime rate as your default shipping method. Make this something with a flat rate.

These usually fix things but here's the annoying part. I've had different customers with this issue. Customer A the fix was to create the sales order in dynamic mode. Customer B the fix was to create the order in non-dynamic mode! So play with that and see what works in your account.

Comment: Yes, It worked by removing shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FedEx/Ups as your shipping carriers, and you have opted to real time rate calculations in shipping methods.

Now while creating a sales order, the shipping method you have opted will calculate the real time shipping rates according to the selected customer's address.

If the customer's address is in their service area, then you can easily calculate the shipping cost, otherwise the system will throw this error.

You can verify it by changing the customer's address. Also, you can check by choosing different shipping methods.

[image]